# Create Classic VM from VHD in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a server in Classic ASM which I want to move to another subscription.

I tried using the move feature on the portal but it throws error that target subscription is not empty.

Are there any way that I can recreate the classic VM from its VHDs and also migrate its IP address to the new Subscription.
I don't want the Generalise the VM.

Thanks.

Comment: another option: migrate classic vm to ARM and after that you can move it to another subscription. that is also better in a sense that classic is depreciated and using it is a real pain nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The client does not plan to migrate to ARM currently.

To migrate the VM to another subscription, I followed the below steps and it worked well.

1- Copy the VM's VHDs to the destination storage account.
2- Create VM Image (Classic) using the VHD which was copied and then create VM out of it.
3- Unfortunately, I was unable to find a way to migrate the public IP address to another subscription.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried using the move feature on the portal but it throws error that target subscription is not empty.

If you want to move ASM resources to a new subscription, you should note:

- All classic resources in the subscription must be moved in the same operation.
- The target subscription must not contain any other classic resources.
- The move can only be requested through a separate REST API for classic moves. The standard Resource Manager move commands don't work when moving classic resources to a new subscription.

To move classic resources to a new subscription, use the REST operations that are specific to classic resources, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources#new-subscription).

Besides, if it is possible, I recommend you to use ARM nowadays, Microsoft released a new management model called Azure Resource Manager (ARM) which provides many new capabilities to manage, and control Azure resources. You could migrate the VM from ASM to ARM, refer to this [link](https://deansuzuki.net/2017/01/11/azure-moving-virtual-machines-from-classic-asm-to-resource-management-arm/). And move it to another subscription, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-move-resources).